# If statement not stopping

Tags: c++

well i am trying to write a code for zodiac signs.
the condition isn't detected as wrong but as I type the word instead of just showing one output it shows every output for different conditions

i tried changing the conditions still the same.

```
  #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
int sign, Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, Virgo, Libra, Scorpio, 
 Sagittarius, Capricorn, Aquarius, Pices;
cout<<"Aries        Taurus     Gemini    Cancer"<<endl;
cout<<"Leo          Virgo      Libra     Scorpio"<<endl;
cout<<"Sagittarius  Capricorn  Aquarius  Pices"<<endl;

cout<<endl;

cout<<"Enter the number Your Zodiac Sign Please: ";
cin>>sign;

if (sign==Aries)
{
 cout<<"Your Zodiac Sign is Aries"<<endl;
 cout<<"You get to show the world exactly who you are and what you can do!"<<endl;
 cout<<"Your lucky number is 17"<<endl;
 cout<<"Your lucky color is Cyan";
}
if (sign==Taurus)
{
 cout<<"Your Zodiac Sign is Taurus"<<endl;
 cout<<"Your partner is in-charge of you today"<<endl;
 cout<<"Your lucky number is 666"<<endl;
 cout<<"Your lucky color is Red";
}
if (sign==Gemini)
{   
 cout<<"Your Zodiac Sign is Gemini"<<endl;
 cout<<"Trust your gut. step out of your comfort zone."<<endl;
 cout<<"Your lucky number is 3"<<endl;
 cout<<"Your lucky color is Pink";
```

for example i typed Aries as my sign. I expect to see the output only under Aries and nothing else.

but the output I'm getting for this code is: I input Aries. the output i get is everything after Aries's supposed output.

Comment: A) You seem to be missing part of the code, B) please indent the code correctly

Comment: yeah the "}" but its not that important. just the code

Comment: What is the number for Aries? Now look at your code, where in the code have you told the computer what the number for Aries is? This is programming by hoping that you get something right, instead of understanding what you need to do. You need to have something like `int Aries = 1, Taurus = 2, ...` in your code (or whatever numbers you've picked for the signs).

Comment: oh.. right my bad. i forgot to edit before publishing

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 4):

None of the variables *Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, Virgo, Libra, corpio, Sagittarius, Capricorn, Aquarius and Pices* are initialized, to compare *sign* with them has an undefined behavior.

Note also you do not check the input just doing `cin>>sign;`, better to do for instance `if (! (cin>>sign)) return 0;` to be sure *sign* was read

---

Perhaps you wanted

```
int sign;

enum Zodiac { Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, Virgo, Libra, Scorpio, Sagittarius, Capricorn, Aquarius, Pices };
```

and in that case you can replace the sequences of *if* by *switch / cases*, or at least to use *else if* from the second *if*

Anyway you always print literal strings, you can put them into an array to reduce the code size :

```
const char * ZodiacDescr[] = {
  "Your Zodiac Sign is Aries\nYou get to show the world exactly who you are and what you can do!\nYour lucky number is 17\nYour lucky color is Cyan",
  "Your Zodiac Sign is Taurus\nYour partner is in-charge of you today\nYour lucky number is 666\nYour lucky color is Red",
  "Your Zodiac Sign is Gemini\nTrust your gut. step out of your comfort zone.\nYour lucky number is 3\nYour lucky color is Pink",
  ...
};
```

and  if code becomes :

```
if ((sign >= Aries) && (sign <= Pices))
  cout << ZodiacDescr[sign] << endl;
else
  cout <<"invalid sign number" << endl;
```

---

If you also always write *Your Zodiac Sign is* and *lucky number* and *lucky color* you can also use a *struct* like:

```
struct { 
  const char * name;
  const char * beh; 
  int number;
  const char * color; 
} ZodiacDescr[] = {
  { "Aries", "You get to show the world exactly who you are and what you can do!", 17, "Cyan"},
  { "Taurus", "Your partner is in-charge of you today", 666, "Red" },
  { "Gemini", "Trust your gut. step out of your comfort zone.", 3, "Pink" },
  ...
};
```

and the code become

```
if ((sign >= Aries) && (sign <= Pices))
  cout << "Your Zodiac Sign is " << ZodiacDescr[sign].name << '\n'
       << ZodiacDescr[sign].beh << '\n'
       << "Your lucky number is " << ZodiacDescr[sign].number << '\n'
       << "Your lucky color is " << ZodiacDescr[sign].color << endl;
else
  cout <<"invalid sign number" << endl;
```

---

But to ask for a number if not practical, better to ask for the name of the sign, for instance :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Zodiac { 
  const char * name;
  const char * beh; 
  int number;
  const char * color; 
};

const Zodiac ZodiacDescr[] = {
  { "Aries", "You get to show the world exactly who you are and what you can do!", 17, "Cyan"},
  { "Taurus", "Your partner is in-charge of you today", 666, "Red" },
  { "Gemini", "Trust your gut. step out of your comfort zone.", 3, "Pink" },
  // ...
};

int main()
{
  string sign;

  cerr << "Enter you zodiac sign please : "; // cerr to flush
  if (cin >> sign) {
    for (auto s : ZodiacDescr) {
      if (s.name == sign) {
        cout << "Your Zodiac Sign is " << s.name << '\n'
          << s.beh << '\n'
            << "Your lucky number is " << s.number << '\n'
              << "Your lucky color is " << s.color << endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << "invalid sign" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra z.cc
./a.oupi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter you zodiac sign please : aze
invalid sign
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter you zodiac sign please : Aries
Your Zodiac Sign is Aries
You get to show the world exactly who you are and what you can do!
Your lucky number is 17
Your lucky color is Cyan
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter you zodiac sign please : Gemini
Your Zodiac Sign is Gemini
Trust your gut. step out of your comfort zone.
Your lucky number is 3
Your lucky color is Pink
```

Of course it is also possible to place the signs into a *map* where the key is the name of the signs rather than in an array to facilitate the search of the sign from its name etc etc

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: @OddCritter I edited my answer with several proposals including asking for the name of the sign rather than its number